# How to setup subscription for android application

Tags: android, subscription

Didn't see the Add subscription button in the Google Play console.
Refer to the screenshot of the Google Play console - subscription section.
currently the app is in review for publishing.
Does it mean that the subscription can only be added after the app is published?
and because I can't add subscription, I set a fixed price for the app.
Can I switch it from fixed price to subscription when I can add subscription?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For adding subscription or in app products you need to upload your app to playstore in testing environment not in production with the billing library specified in gradle.
Once you upload the apk, play console will show you the options for adding subscriptions.

Read the official docs here.

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/getting-ready#enable
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/140504?hl=en
https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/subscriptions