# Google in app purchase version 5 purchase verification issue

Tags: java, android, kotlin, in-app-purchase, play-billing-library

I'm unable to verify the purchase or particular item after being purchased from the google play billing version.

Is there any way to get the verification of the item purchase from email, or from the token after the item is purchased?

hope this exists in google play, if not than what we can do?

Note: I'm using version 5.0.0

Comment: after the purchase from google billing library, you get a purchase token. For that you have to acknowledge your purchase.

Comment: refer my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/73795479/8101634

Comment: yes we get that. but how to validate that. from billing again

Comment: why you have to validate that again?

Comment: to make sure that it's on second device getting it back, kind of restore without own server side

Comment: acknowledge your purchases. Google provides the way to acknowledge purchase

Comment: how can i acknowledge in google billing version 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have purchased using google play billing library, you will get the purchase token in `PurchasesUpdateListener` .

After this you can acknowledge your purchases using `AcknowledgePurchaseParams`. You have to set the purchase token in this.

```
val acknowledgePurchaseParams = AcknowledgePurchaseParams.newBuilder()
                        .setPurchaseToken(purchase.purchaseToken)
val ackPurchaseResult =
                     billingClient.acknowledgePurchase(acknowledgePurchaseParams.build())
```

For more info refer this [link](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate#process)

Comment: Can we do it after several days to acknowledge the purchase from the product token?

Comment: and one more thing does the above method tell us about the valid purchase against the token or does it just save that token itself assuming its purchase has been done?

Comment: if your purchase is acknowledged then it is valid