# in app billing version 5 not launchPurchaseFlow

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play-console

I am using version 5.1 of Google In-App Payments.
But when I click on the product, the value of List list in the function
queryProductDetailsAsync is zero.
I have also added the product in the panel.
What is the problem?

```
ImmutableList productList = ImmutableList.of(
        //Product 1 = index is 0
        QueryProductDetailsParams.Product.newBuilder()
                .setProductId("test_billing")
                .setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.INAPP)
                .build()
);


QueryProductDetailsParams params = QueryProductDetailsParams.newBuilder()
        .setProductList(productList)
        .build();

billingClient.queryProductDetailsAsync(params, new ProductDetailsResponseListener() {
    @Override
    public void onProductDetailsResponse(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult, @NonNull List<ProductDetails> list) {
        if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && !list.isEmpty()) {
            // Handle the success of the consume operation.
            //inja find , set beshe


            for (ProductDetails productDetails : list) {
                if (productDetails.getProductId().equals("test_billing")) {
                    rl1.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                        launchPurchaseFlow(productDetails);
                    });
                }
            }

          

        }else{

        }
```

google play billing
android

Comment: I have a working kotlin version for Billing Library 5.1, if you can convert that to java let me know I will share it with you.

Comment: Have you uploaded the app on playstore? If yes, then is your app approved?

Comment: @primo The program is loaded in draft mode

Comment: Refer to my answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73795479/8101634. draft mode will not work. You have upload an apk in open testing